# Avg of last 3 months

Tags: expression, average, qlikview, rolling-computation

I have constructed a demo on

there is  problem of  3 month ratio  I am looking for when it’s Jan it will show Jan amount, if Feb then sum(Jan and Feb), if March then (Jan and feb and mar), if apr then sum(feb,mar,apr).

for April (Feb , March and April ) is because if we check last months there is Jan , Feb , March and April

but here we need only 3 months so this should be start form Feb ..

Answer (score 0):

To calculate 3 month rolling average in chart please use:

```
RangeAvg(Above(Sum(B_Amount),0,3))
```